# How can I normalize features while preserving information about the original values?

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, feature-engineering

I am trying to feed a neural network information about a stock (100s of features concerning price, MA, volume etc.). To ensure training stability, I normalize the features to have `mean of 0.0` and a `standard deviation of 1.0`.

However, I thought that for stock prices, the absolute prices of the instrument would also be relevant. One way I can think of this is the [psychological effect of "round numbers"](https://atas.net/market-theory/the-magic-of-round-numbers/), meaning we like to see clean numbers as important markers. So for an asset values 99.78€ currently, the 100€ marker will likely be an important driving factor for the price development. However, the information of those possible markers gets lost when normalizing each feature to fit a normal distribution.

**How can I set up the features to not lose this viable information that gets lost when normalizing?**

My initial thought was to supply the model with the important zones by providing them as extra features (e.g. the first round number above and below, say 100€ and 99€ for the example above). But this adds extra (perhaps unneeded) complexity for the model. What are your suggestions? Am I missing an important aspect here?

Comment: You could normalize the price, and include a second feature that indicates whether the price is a round number. False vs. True (0 vs. 1). I would recommend doing this even when not normalising, as when you feed the price as a single variable to the network its quite complex to learn that round numbers are important. Alternatively you could use two features one for the value before Euro/Dollar and one for the cent value. This way you can normalise both idenpendently

Comment: That is not what I meant. Say my price is 99€, there would be a largy psychological marker at 100€ and maybe one at 90€ aswell. How would I model that in my input? Please tell my how I can update the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

I will just answer here because of the better text editor.

So if you believe that the neural network will be capable of "learning" from the single numeric input of price that "round" values are preferred of "non-round" values, then normalisation of the variable should not be an issue as it will retain the relative relationship of values between each other. So, the neural network would be capable of learning of this relationship, because for the neural network the concept of "round" values is arbitrary and it would just learn to associated specific values with prefered values.

However, I believe that this is a really hard task to learn for a neural network. You could simplify this task by normalizing the price and have an additional collum that indicated whether the value is considered round or not:

`(100,1),(99,0), (98,0), (97,0) ... (80,1)`

However, this way you only focus on round values, but there might be patterns that can be discovered by the network, that you are not aware of.

I would maybe try to provide values in a tuple of three:
`(1,0,0), (0,9,9), (0,9,8), (0,9,7) ... (0,8,0)`

This way you can ensure that patterns are much easiere learned. For example round values always have a three at the third position.

Comment: This is really not what I meant... the input is much bigger than just a single number, I want to preserve the information about the prices that get lost when normalizing (e.g. their closeness to round numbers like 100 and 1000, maybe even numbers like 333 or 444 that are psychologically important). Also, the input consists of floats so the values will most likely never be exactly a round number

Comment: I updated the question, hope this clarifies

Comment: So you can extend the approach from above to 99.78. (0,9,9,7,8) and 100 would be 100 (1,0,0,0,0).  Or if you have even more digits you can obviosuly extened this
The relative relationship between values is not lost when normalizing. So the pattern still exist in the data, but it is not necessarily obvious to the human anymore. However, as I said before these patterns are harder to learn if you feed it a single float value as opposed to using 5 integers (or more). Using integers it must simply learn that the last three inputs must be zero to be liked by the human.

Comment: I mean just as an example a new neural network can learn to differentiate identify even and odd numbers, however that is really difficult for a network to learn. And the question now remains can it predict this property for a numbers outside the range of the training set. It would have to approximate this function (or something alike) cos(pi*x-pi)/2 + 0.5.  However, if you just split the numbers into digits it "just" hast to learn that values 0,2,4,6,8, are associated with the label even. 
And your case is much more complex then even vs odd

Comment: I understand your point better now, thanks for the explanation & example!